# Swift - Where should I set the values for custom cell - CustomCell or ViewController?

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have a custom cell class say UserDetailsCustomCell. I have 4 labels in this class Name, Gender, DOB, Address. Whats the best place to set the values in the labels. Shall I pass all these values to cell class and let cell class display these values or shall I set these values in ViewController cellForRowAtIndexPath method.
What is the best way and why?

Thanks

Comment: Well in my opinion UserDetailsCustomCell is best place to set those values, you can set properties getter and setter in UserDetailsCustomCell and pass those values to UserDetailsCustomCell method from ViewController cellForRowAtIndexPath.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to keep your logic related to cell's data population inside your cell. Create a method which populates your cell data and call it from your viewcontroller.

Answer (score 0):

i think it's best to encapsulate your view logics inside your view. so other people don't get involved with view's logic when they want to use them.

for example

```
final class UserDetailsCustomCell: UICollectionViewCell {

    var user: User! {
        didSet {
            guard user != nil else { return }
            nameLabel.text = user.name
            genderLabel.text = user.gender
            addressLabel.text = user.address
            dateOfBirthLabel.text = user.dateOfBirth
        }
    }

    private @IBOutlet weak var nameLabel: UILabel!
    private @IBOutlet weak var genderLabel: UILabel!
    private @IBOutlet weak var dateOfBirthLabel: UILabel!
    private @IBOutlet weak var addressLabel: UILabel!

}
```

here when someone wants to use UserDetailsCustomCell they dont need to know how to set labels or any other view logics. they just set user and the cell do the rest for them

```
cell.user = someUser
```

Answer (score 0):

first create objectModel to aggregate the data:

```
struct UserDetailsObjectModel {
    var username: String
    var gender: String
    var dob: String
    var address: String
}
```

create dataSource var in UserDetailsCustomCell:

```
class UserDetailsCustomCell: UICollectionViewCell {

    var dataSource: UserDetailsObjectModel? {
        willSet {
            if let userDetails = newValue {
                // do what ever u want with the user data
            }
        }
    }
}
```

finally pass the userDetailsObject AKA dataSource in cellForItem method

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "userDetailsCell", for: indexPath) as! UserDetailsCustomCell

        let dataSource = UserDetailsObjectModel("insert the data in each param!")
        cell.dataSouece = dataSource
        return cell
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is one of the way for passing JSON values in `CustomCell`

**Sample JSON Format**

```
{
"studentListJSON" : [

        {
            "name" : "mcdonal",
            "age" : "27",
            "gender" : "male"
        },
        {
            "name" : "jack",
            "age" : "29",
            "gender" : "male"
        },
        {
            "name" : "rose",
            "age" : "24",
            "gender" : "female"
        },
    ]
}
```

**Singleton declaration**

```
class Singleton: NSObject {
    static let sharedInstance = Singleton()
    var studentListJSON = NSArray()
}
```

**JSON Parsing**

```
func JSONParsing()
{
let url = URL(string: urlString) // YOUR API URL
URLSession.shared.dataTask(with:url!) { (data, response, error) in
  if error != nil {
    print(error)
  } else {
    do {

      let parsedData = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!) as! NSDictionary
      Singleton.sharedInstance.studentListJSON = parsedData.value(forKey: "studentListJSON") as! NSArray

      // RELOAD CollectionView in main thread, if Singleton.sharedInstance.studentListJSON.count > 0

    } catch let error as NSError {
      print(error)
    }
  }

}.resume()
}
```

Parse JSON Array to `Singleton.sharedInstance.studentListJSON`. Then `reloadData()` with `numberOfItems` as `Singleton.sharedInstance.studentListJSON.count`

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "userDetailsCell", for: indexPath) as! UserDetailsCustomCell

      let datasDict = Singleton.sharedInstance.studentListJSON[indexPath.item] as! NSDictionary
      cell.name.text = datasDict.value(forKey: "name") as! String
      cell.age.text = datasDict.value(forKey: "age") as! String    
      cell.gender.text = datasDict.value(forKey: "gender") as! String
    return cell
}
```